# .NET Framework 4.5 missing from list of targeted frameworks

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just purchased and installed Visual Studio 2012 on my dev laptop (Windows 7 x64). I create a new project and am rather surprised to see that the .NET Framework 4.5 is missing from the list of targeted frameworks when creating a new project/app as well as from the project properties on an existing app.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this problem?.I am also facing the same issue .The issue is listed in the following link but no suitable solution[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/2d9cc718-2675-4e6b-9fa1-858bf6469ad4/)

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/efe91261-c52a-44bd-9fe7-199d86ed9733/) suggests uninstalling, rebooting and re-installing Visual Studio 2012.